# Excel file information shared over LOOKUP formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have a Vlookup to a shared drive that only 3 people have access to.  But other people who do not have access to the shared drive are also able to access this data

For Example:

I type in the ID and see the name and other sensitive information. The name and other sensitive information comes from a file that is stored in a shared drive which can be read only by three (3) users.
But when I forward this file to someone else who does not have access to this shared drive, they are able to put in the ID and get the sensitive information.

I'd like to stop this from happening, what could be wrong?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Can you add information about your spreadsheet and formulae so that we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give an answer for Excel 2010 because you didn't specify a version but a similar process is similar in any at least 2003-2013 although which things you actually click may be in different places.

Here's the short answer: Use a query to pull in all the data from the private file and set it up to not save the data so it has to re-query every time.

Here's the process:

1. In your public file, create a new worksheet
2. In the Data ribbon, click on the `From Other Sources` drop-down at the far left and then click `From Microsoft Query`
3. It'll ask you to choose a data source so select `Excel Files` and click OK
4. Browse to the private file, select it, and click OK (Yes, MSQuery uses an insanely old dialog box so it may feel awkward trying to find your file.)
5. Select the worksheet that contains the data you want to bring in (if it's more than one worksheet, then repeat this process for each one)
6. Finish out the query setup and return the data to MS Excel (It's mostly just clicking Next and OK)
7. You should have a table of data in your shared file that has all the data from the sheet you chose in the private file.
8. Right-click somewhere within that table, and click `Table` and then `External Data Properties`
9. Click the icon to the right of the `Name` field in the dialog box (looks like a hand holding a sheet of paper) to open the `Connection Properties`
10. In the `Usage` tab - which should be where are already - check the box labeled `Refresh data when opening this file` and the one labeled `Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook`.
11. Rewrite all your formulas to reference this data instead of the actual private file.

Effectively, this erases all the data whenever the file is saved and closed. It tries to refresh the data when the file is opened but only those with access to the private file can actually get to it.

The only downside is that now you have to deal with the error messages for the people that don't have access to the file. (I don't have an answer for that one right now besides telling people to click Cancel when it pops up.)